# Classification method for unevenly spread data

Tags: python, statistics, classification, distribution

I have several datasets with very unevenly distributed values: Most values are very low, but a few are very high, for example, in the histogram screenshot or even more extreme.

I am actually interested in the differences in the high values.

So what I am looking for is a classification method that sets many break values where there are few data values and large classes where there are many values. Maybe something like a reversed quantile classification.

Do you have a suggestion on which algorithm could help with this task, preferably in Python?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are using pandas, couldn't you just select the values above your chosen threshold and analyze the difference seperately?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(your data)

df_to_analyze_large_values = df[df.your_Column_of_interest > 100000]
```

Comment: but which algorithm would I use for the values above the threshold?